# HorizontalPager page fills entire screen and block tabs jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack, please help me, I'm pretty sure that this is a simple question:
My problem is that page content block tabs.
Here is the image:
[image]

as you can see, `hello` text is on the tabs.
Here is my code:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    val pages = listOf("One", "two")
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
            )
        }
    ) {
        pages.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(title) },
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.scrollToPage(index)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        count = pages.size,
        state = pagerState,
    ) { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> {
                Text(text = "hello", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            }
            1 -> {

            }
        }
    }
```

I want the `Text` to fill the entire screen, but below the tabs.
Any fixed constraints are bad for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was just a matter of wrapping everything inside `Column {}`